# How would I duplicate form elements AND the data inside them with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, forms

See this form - http://schnell.dreamhosters.com/form.php

This form has a portion of it where you enter data and can choose to add more of the same data by clicking a button called 'Add A Site' and it will make another of that section to enter another site.  This is the jQuery that performs the duplication...

```
$(function ()   {
    var sites = 1;
    var siteform = $("#site1").html();

    $(".addsites").live("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        sites++;
        $("#events").append("<div id='site" + sites + "'>"
            + "<br /><hr><br />"
            + siteform
            + "<center><button class='removesites' title='site"
            + sites + "'>Remove This Site</button><br />"
            + "<button class='addsites'>Add Another Site</button>"
            + "</center></div>");           
    });

    $(".removesites").live("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#" + id).remove();
    });     
});
```

The duplication works perfectly, but one thing that's bugging me is that when I have to enter data for someone claiming a LOT of sites, it gets very annoying having to repeat same or similar parts of this section of the form (like every site is in the same city, on the same day, by the same person, etc.)  So I had the idea that with each duplication, the values of the form elements would also carry over and I just edit what's not the same.  The current implementation only duplicates the elements, not the data.  I'm not sure how to easily copy the data into new sections, and I can't find any jQuery tools to do that.

PS - This part isn't as important, but I've also considered using this same form to load the data back in for viewing/editing, etc.  The only problem with this is that the reprinting of the form means that there will be a form section with the id "Site7" or something, but jQuery starts its numbering at 1, always.  I've thought about using selectors to find the highest number site and start off the variable 'sites' at that number, but I'm not sure how.  Any advice how to do this, or a better system overall, would be much appreciated.

Comment: from the documentation .clone() reads like it's what you might need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured this out.  It's, more or less, an expansion on Alex Pakka's answer.

```
        sites++;
        $("#events").append("<div id='site" + sites + "'>"
            + "<hr><br />"
            + siteform
            + "<center><button class='removesites' title='site"
            + sites + "'>Remove This Site</button><br />");
        $("#site1").find("input:checked, input:text, textarea, select").each(function() {
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var val = $(this).val();
            var checked = $(this).attr("checked");
            var selected = $(this).attr("selectedIndex");

            $('#site' + sites + ' [name="'+name+'"]').val(val);
            $('#site' + sites + ' [name="'+name+'"]').attr("checked", checked);
            $('#site' + sites + ' [name="'+name+'"]').attr("selectedIndex", selected);
        });
```

I used extra vars for readability sake, but it should do just as fine if you didn't and used the methods directly.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You could consider using [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode) to truely clone the previous site-div and (by passing `true` to `cloneNode`) all of its descendants and their attributes. Just know that the clone will have the same `id` as the original, so you'll have to manually set its id afterwards</strike>

Try this in your click-function

```
var clone = $("#site" + sites).clone(true, true); // clone the last div
sites++; // increment the number of divs
clone.attr('id', "site" + sites); // give the clone a unique id
$("#events").append(clone); // append it to the container
```

---

As Scuzzy points out in a comment jQuery *does* have its own [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method (I don't use jQuery much, so I didn't know, and I didn't bother to check before answering). Probably better to use jQuery's method than the built-in `cloneNode` DOM method, since you're already using jQuery for event listeners. I've updated the code

Comment: Ok the cloning works and does what I wanted.  Only problem now is that for some reason the section won't duplicate more than once.  [b]Edit - Fixed it.  All good now.[/b]

Comment: Just noticed the cloning doesn't copy the values of dropdown lists and textareas.  Nothing mentioned about it on the documentation.

Comment: @MathiasSchnell: Have you tried `.clone(true, true);`? According to the jQuery docs, that should copy the entire hierarchy completely. I forgot the 2nd `true` when I edited my answer. Again, I'm not a jQuery-guy, but I think it'll work

Comment: Yeah, tried `.clone(true, true)` already.  Also the id wasn't setting properly originally, but I fixed that with `clone.attr("id", "site" + sites);`

Comment: @MathiasSchnell: Hmm... well, I can't tell you why it's not copying everything as it should (but perhaps you can fix that using some of the other answers here). And the `id` thing was my mistake - I should have realized that `clone()` returns a jQuery wrapper object, and not an actual element, so using `attr` is the correct solution there

Answer (score 1):

You want to itterate over the input fields in siteform and store them in an object using their name attribute as a key.

Then after the duplication of the object you made and look for the equivelant fields in the new duplicated form ans set their values.

Somthing like this (not tested, just the idea)

```
var obj = new Object();

$("#site1 input").each(function(){
    obj[this.id] = this.value;
);

// Dupicate form

$.each(obj, function(key, value){
    $('#newform input[name="'+key+'"]').value = value;
});
```

Mind you these two each() functions differ from each other.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/
http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

The query to transfer values is quite simple (please, check the selector for all the right types on the form):

`$("#site1").find("input[checked], input:text, input:hidden, input:password, input:submit, option:selected, textarea")
            //.filter(":disabled")
            .each(function()
{
   $('#site2 [name="'+this.name+'"]').val(this.value);
}`

Comment: Partially works.  Selection lists and checkboxes aren't being copied over.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to create a function for registering the event! Its very important because when the DOM is loaded, all new attributes need to be registrated to the DOM.

Small example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#click-me').click(function(){
            registerClickEvent();
        })

        function registerClickEvent(){
            $('<input type="text" name="input_field_example[]">').appendTo('#the-div-you-want')
        }

        registerClickEvent();
    })
</script>
```